# One or more of the auto-generated multi-APKs exceeds the maximum allowed size of 150 MB

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, apk, google-play-console

So am creating a mobile game in unity which sizes 220MBs, And when I upload it to google play console it shows me this error, I literally Searched everywhere In Internet but didn't solve the problem, Am Shocked because It has to be a very common problem but there are not many resources about it, And there are games like pubg mobile etc.. which sizes nearly 3GB so what's that? I also tried PAD but it didn't work so please is there any way to solve that?
Thanks...

Comment: You can lower your app size by compressing textures and meshes. And if that is not the case you can create binary file by going into Player Settings -> Publishing Settings -> Split Application Binary. Just tick this option and now unity will create two files 1. Apk and 2. OBB file. Apk files is smaller and OBB file contains all the data. Now you can upload it to google playstore.

Comment: apps i know of that use multiple GB of space use content loaders, while the APK itself is only 20-30MB. They usually load the app content at the first start of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those games like PUBG don't download the entirety of the app from the store. The launcher is downloaded from the store, and then the additional content is downloaded seperately.

There are two issues, firstly appstore no longer accepts apks so the split binary option is no longer viable.

You should look into using addressables. [https://learn.unity.com/project/getting-started-with-addressables][1]

With addressables, you upload the asset bundles to either unity cdn/s3 or similar, and that will effectively drop your app size proportionally to the asset bundle sizes.